"Stream" messages from rust to javascript
I want to implement a logger for the log create, that allows me to stream / asynchronously publish the messages to JavaScript, so they can be displayed to the user.
Currently, I have a very simple setup, that requires JavaScript to "ask" for the logs, which isn't optimal, since I'm not really in a context, where I only want to display the logs, after something is done, but while it's happening.
static LOGGER: Logger = Logger::new();

#[wasm_bindgen]
pub struct Logger {
    logs: Mutex<Vec<String>>,
    level: Mutex<LogLevel>,
}

impl Logger {
    pub fn init_once() {
        static INIT: Once = Once::new();
        INIT.call_once(|| {
            log::set_logger(&LOGGER).unwrap();
            log::set_max_level(log::LevelFilter::max());
        })
    }
}

#[wasm_bindgen]
impl Logger {
    pub fn get_logs() -> Vec<String> {
        let logs = LOGGER
            .logs
            .lock()
            .expect("failed to acquire a lock to logger while getting logs");

        logs.clone()
    }
}

I've tried adding a add_log_listener and remove_log_listener method, but found that this doesn't work, since js_sys::Function is at some point a *mut u* (I'm guessing that some sort of pointer? And for some reason it's *mut?), which doesn't implement Send, which is required by the log::Log trait.
I don't have any particular visions on how the API should work, as long as the logs can be displayd in a asynchrounous manner :)

PS:
The displaying is currently being done by the Monaco Editor, so just passing in an HTML-Element and appending to it, isn't that easy. And I'm also not sure if that would be more thread safe. Haven't looked too deep into it. And I really would like the display logic to not necessarily be mixed with my logging logic... if possible.
I have also thought about polling the logger with a setInterval from JavaScript, but that sounds quite hacky. It shouldn't be a problem right now, I think, but as soon as more than one thingy calls get_logs() (and consequently clear_logs()), that wouldn't work anymore.

There are two options:

Store the callback in a thread local. Unless you actually use WASM threads (which are unstable anyway), this will be the same.
Create a specific thread that owns the callback, and send events to it via channels.

However, the best strategy actually is to do neither, and instead do what you dismissed as hacky - setInterval(). That is because logs can be emitted very fast, and calling JS from WASM and even more writing to the DOM is very slow, so if you will do that for every log record this will hurt your speed. You only want that at a constant rate, since the human eye cannot tell the difference anyway.

Yeah, I figured. I'm actually trying to implement a "queue" and polling right now. Thank you for the advice.
And no, I don't use any threads whatsoever.
I will update my post and or add an answer once I get it working :)

I have posted my resulting code, in case you're interested in critiquing, aka improving, it :P. Thanks for your help.

Alright, I managed to create something that sort of does what I want. In courtesy of https://stackoverflow.com/a/79108001/10315665 and various other resources, I decided that pushing the logs to a queue, and then polling them in an interval will suffice.
I acchieved something like that with:
#[wasm_bindgen]
impl Logger {
    fn get_logs_from(idx: usize) -> Vec<String> {
        let logs = LOGGER
            .logs
            .lock()
            .expect("failed to acquire a lock to logs while trying to get logs from index");

        logs[idx..].to_vec()
    }

    pub fn new_subscriber() -> LogSubscriber {
        let curr_idx = LOGGER
            .logs
            .lock()
            .expect("failed to acquire a lock to logs while trying to create new log subscriber")
            .len();
        LogSubscriber::new(curr_idx)
    }
}

#[wasm_bindgen]
pub struct LogSubscriber {
    curr_idx: usize,
}

impl LogSubscriber {
    fn new(curr_idx: usize) -> Self {
        Self {
            curr_idx,
        }
    }
}

#[wasm_bindgen]
impl LogSubscriber {
    pub fn get_next_logs(&mut self) -> Vec<String> {
        let logs = Logger::get_logs_from(self.curr_idx);
        self.curr_idx += logs.len();
        return logs;
    }
}

In JavaScript, the polling chan then simply be done with:
const wasmLogSubscriber = Logger.new_subscriber();
setInterval(() => {
    for (const log of wasmLogSubscriber.get_next_logs()) {
        console.log(log);
    }
}, 100);

Or, alternatively, and probably what I will ultimately will go for:
#[wasm_bindgen]
extern "C" {
    fn setInterval(closure: &Closure<dyn FnMut()>, millis: u32) -> f64;
    fn clearInterval(token: f64);
}

#[wasm_bindgen]
impl LogSubscriber {
    pub fn start_poll(&mut self, callback: js_sys::Function) {
        let mut curr_idx = 0;
        let closure = Closure::new(move || {
            let logs = Logger::get_logs_from(curr_idx);

            for log in logs.iter() {
                let _ = callback.call1(&JsValue::NULL, &JsValue::from_str(&log));
            }

            curr_idx += logs.len();
        });

        self.interval_id = Some(setInterval(&closure, 100));
        self.closure = Some(closure);
    }
}

impl Drop for LogSubscriber {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        if let Some(interval_id) = self.interval_id {
            clearInterval(interval_id);
        }
    }
}


const wasmLogSubscriber = Logger.new_subscriber();
wasmLogSubscriber.start_poll((message: string) => {
    console.log(message);
});


Would be cool if there was an example, though, on how to do event emitters, because that's a quite frequently used pattern in JavaScript.

Is there a reason not to clear already-seen logs, to prevent memory usage from ever growing?

@ChayimFriedman Only to enable multiple subscribers. Other than that, no.
